# jQuery to Javascript equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JavaScript and also jQuery and have been trying to convert this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#var').val('value');
    document.forms[0].submit();
});
```

to use only JavaScript, can anyone explain the equivalent functions in js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) for equivalent of `ready`.

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading. A very different event - load - should be used only to detect a fully-loaded page. It is an incredibly popular mistake for people to use load where DOMContentLoaded would be much more appropriate, so be cautious.

Use [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) for id selector.

> Returns a reference to the element by its ID.

Javascript Code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) { // Equivalent of ready
    document.getElementById('var').value = 'value';
    document.forms[0].submit();
});
```